# How can I display the key names in a JSON file as labels with Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am new to Swift and iOS development. I would appreciate some guidance on how to display the key names in a JSON file as labels.

Using Swift 5 and the following JSON data (this is a snippet of a larger file):

```
{
  "color": {
      "white": { "value": "#fff" },
      "black": { "value": "#000" },
      "gray": {
        "10": { "value": "#f5f7f8" },
        "20": { "value": "#e8eced" },
        "30": { "value": "#d5d9db" },
        "40": { "value": "#b6bec2" },
        "50": { "value": "#8e999e" },
        "60": { "value": "#69757a" },
        "70": { "value": "#495257" },
        "80": { "value": "#333a3d" },
        "90": { "value": "#1f2426" }
   }
```

... I need create a grid that displays the color name (the key) as a label and the actual color next to it ... something like this:

```
White:  (display a white rectangle)
Black:  (display a black rectangle)
Gray10: (display a gray rectangle)
Gray20: (display a darker gray rectangle)
Gray30: (display a darker gray rectangle)
...
...
Gray90: (display a very dark gray rectangle)
```

I am able to parse/decode and iterate though the JSON file using Swift to `print()` the color hex values.

What I cannot figure out is how to display the actual key names (the color names) as labels.

Here's what I have working in my playground so far. I have not figured out how to processes the nested "Gray" color values yet, so I excluded them from my code.

It does print out the color hex values. I commented out the code to print the `key` because it does not work.

```
import Foundation

let json = """
{
  "color": {
    "white": { "value": "#fff" },
    "black": { "value": "#000" }
  }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct color: Codable {
//  let key: String
    let value: String
}

struct Entry: Codable {
    let color: [String: color]
}

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
  let parsedJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode(Entry.self, from: json)
  for color in parsedJSON.color {
//  print(color.value.key)
    print(color.value.value)
  }
}


Thanks!
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see the code that iterates through the json. I think it will be pretty simple to tweak the code and display the names of the colors then.

Comment: `print(color.key)`.

Comment: Well that was easy. I thought I had tried that, but apparently not. Thanks @rmaddy. Now I need to figure out how to work with nested JSON. I'll make another post for that question. Thanks again.